# Best way to create schema in embedded HSQL database

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hsqldb, embedded-database

I'm currently using the following setup to create a schema in an embedded database before running my tests against it

In my application context

```
<jdbc:embedded-database id="dataSource" type="HSQL">
    <jdbc:script location="classpath:createSchema.sql" />
</jdbc:embedded-database>
```

createSchema.sql

```
create schema ST_TEST AUTHORIZATION DBA;
```

hibernate properties

```
<properties>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect" />
    <property name="hibernate.default_schema" value="ST_TEST"/>
    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop" />
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
    <property name="hibernate.use_sql_comments" value="true" />
    <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="false" />
</properties>
```

My question is is this the best way to do this. Or can i use a different schema name in my properties? or set the schema name in the jdbc:embedded-database element

Answer (score 11, accepted):

By default HSQL creates a schema called PUBLIC. [source: HSQL documentation](http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/databaseobjects-chapt.html#dbc_schemas_schema_objects)

Seeing as the schema name is never seen in the tests (named queries/entity manager to do the interactions) you can change the hibernate properties to use this PUBLIC schema

```
<properties>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect" />
    <property name="hibernate.default_schema" value="PUBLIC"/>
    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop" />
</properties>
```

OR
just leave out the default_schema from the properties list and it uses PUBLIC anyway

```
<properties>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect" />
    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop" />
</properties>
```

Comment: what about if there are two schema in embedded hsqldb ?

Answer (score 4):

You can use this code in your Base Testing class, and call it using @BeforeClass annotation (for Junit). I do it like this.

```
    EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder builder = new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder();
    builder = builder.setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.HSQL).addScript(
            "createSchema.sql");
    builder.setName("MyDatabase");
    EmbeddedDatabase db = builder.build();
```